# Best way to add (enqueue) scripts and styles to Wordpress (functions.php)

Tags: wordpress

So this is a basic question, but I've seen multiple variations for this.

But what is the "best", most clean and proper way to add scripts and styles to your Wordpress website?

Comment: This is only one recommended way to enqueue styles and scripts, which is the way described in the official developer documentation [Wordpress.org Including CSS & JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). What variations are you referring to? But you rarely see any other way described to do this, so if there is a specific example you have seen then include it in your question so we can see what it is and why it might be used, and might be able to answer your question.

Comment: Some info about the [difference between registering and enqueueing styles & scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763486/should-you-specify-dependencies-in-both-wp-register-script-style-and-wp-enqueue/62767238#62767238)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to hook an enqueue function onto the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and use `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions in this, with proper dependencies to ensure scripts are loaded in the correct order.

```
function my_enqueue_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_script('my-script-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script.js', ['jquery'], 'v1.0');
  wp_enqueue_style('my-css-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css', [], 'v1.0');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets');
// ..and if you need them to be present under wp-admin:
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets');
```

**Edit:** the location to your assets should either depend on your plugin or theme directory. Depending on which you chose, you either have to use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` or `get_template_directory_uri()` and append the relative path.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! But when I alter the path of my files while using your code, it won't be able to find those files.

Comment: I added more details about how to specify the URL depending on the plugin or theme path. If you meant "alter" the path as in move those files elsewhere, of course you'll always have to adapt the relative part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to include styles and scripts in my opinion is to first register and then include.

For styles:

```
function prefix_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style('my_style_1', 'url_to_source');
    wp_register_style('my_style_2', 'url_to_source');
    wp_enqueue_style( array('my_style_1','my_style_2') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_styles' );
```

For scripts:

```
function prefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_script_1', 'url_to_source', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
    wp_register_script('my_script_2', 'url_to_source', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( array('my_script_1','my_script_2') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```